# How to parse and read Json formatted text?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a File with following formatted Json

```
{
  "Id": 0,
  "MsgId": 125,
  "ExceptionDetails": "whatever2"
}


{
  "Id": 1,
  "MsgId": 135,
  "ExceptionDetails": "whatever2"
}
```

THIS IS EXACTLY HOW IT IS IN A FILE WITH NO BRAKETS

I need to parse this text file and get the values of these Keys, for instance in this example I need to get the 0 and 1

```
var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\development\commonArea\test3.txt");

var objects = JArray.Parse(json); // parse as array

foreach (JObject root in objects)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JToken> app in root)
    {
        if (app.Key == "Id")
        {
            var appName2 = app.Key;
            Console.WriteLine(I HAVE NO IDEA);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var objects = JArray.Parse(json); // parse as array  

foreach (JObject jobject in objects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(jobject.Value<int>("Id"));
}
```

prints:

```
0
1
```

You presented an invalid JSON. I've modified it, so that it became a valid JSON array:

```
[
    { "Id": 0, "MsgId": 125, "ExceptionDetails": "whatever2" },
    { "Id": 1, "MsgId": 135, "ExceptionDetails": "whatever2" }
]
```

Comment: Then show Ilya some love and mark it as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Make a class that matches and then use a Deserializer. This is using the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MsgId { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionDetails { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public RootObject DeserializeClass()
    {
         JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
         RootObject obj = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject >(JSONSTRING);
         return obj;
     }
}
```

Comment: OP has a array of objects, I doubt it can be represented as single `Class` instance with one `int Id` field.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov your right, i just did not notice that because the json was funky. edit above.